# Secure text field takes too long to hide content

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I just upgraded my iPhone to iOS 11, and noticed, that whenever I am entering data in a secure Textfield, like a users PIN for my iOS application, It takes a while for it to hide and replace it with the secure dot.

I really need to hide it at the instant moves on to next character, It was working in iOS 10

ANy Ideas?.

Comment: It's working for me like it always worked. I'm speculating that your device got slower with iOS 11.

Comment: its an iPhone 7 with 128 GB storage, I dont think memory could be the issue

Comment: Some users have reported that native keyboard in iOS11 is quite slow (all devices reporting the issue). A temporary solution is to use a third party keyboard. If it works, then the issue is with iOS11, and you can't really do something about it.